# Visual Studio own collapsed outline will be expanded

Tags: visual-studio, vsx, outline

my problem is that Visual Studio (vs2013) opens my created and collapsed outline.
the goal I want to achieve is to automatically close the first comment in a source code file in the window activate event.
background is that we have very big fileheadercomments (visual source safe checkin history) in our source files.

I wrote an extension that creates an outline block on the first comment in a file an collapse it. This works fine for files that are already open.

BUT if the file is opened newly (**FileOpen/DocumentOpen**) the outline will be expanded after a few seconds. I think at exactly the time, when the automatic outlining of visual studio is finished?!

also if I execute the command Edit.StopAutomaticOutling before my outlining. after 2 to 3 seconds the outline will be expanded.

here my code for outlining:

`// Outlining stoppen

try

{

    _dte.ExecuteCommand("Edit.StopOutlining");

}

catch (Exception)

{

}



// Oberflächenänderungen abschalten

_dte.SuppressUI = true;



TextSelection ts = _dte.ActiveDocument.Selection as TextSelection;

if (ts != null)

{

    // alte Sektion merken

    TextPoint oldAnchor = ts.AnchorPoint.CreateEditPoint();

    TextPoint oldActive = ts.ActivePoint.CreateEditPoint();



    // Kommentare und Leerzeilen zusammenfassen

    EditPoint edit_point = ts.ActivePoint.CreateEditPoint();

    edit_point.StartOfDocument();



    bool bWasComment = true;

    bool bInBlock = false;

    string line = "";

    while (bWasComment && !edit_point.AtEndOfDocument)

    {

        line = edit_point.GetLines(edit_point.Line, edit_point.Line + 1);

        if (!bInBlock)

        {

            if (line.Trim().StartsWith("/"))

            {

                bInBlock = true;

                bWasComment = true;

            }

            else if (line.Trim().StartsWith("//"))

            {

                bWasComment = true;

            }

            else if (line.Trim() == "")

            {

                bWasComment = true;

            }

            else

            {

                // was anderes

                bWasComment = false;

            }

        }

        else

        {

            if (line.Trim().EndsWith("/"))

            {

                bInBlock = false;

            }

            bWasComment = true;

        }



        if (!bWasComment)

        {

            if (!edit_point.AtStartOfDocument)

            {

                edit_point.LineUp();

            }

        }

        else

        {

            // weiter

            edit_point.LineDown();

        }

    }



    // letze Leerzeilen wieder hoch

    if (!bWasComment)

    {

        line = edit_point.GetLines(edit_point.Line, edit_point.Line + 1);

        while (!edit_point.AtStartOfDocument && line.Trim() == "")

        {

            edit_point.LineUp();

            line = edit_point.GetLines(edit_point.Line, edit_point.Line + 1);

        }



        edit_point.EndOfLine();

    }



    // Outline erstellen und zuklappen

    ts.MoveToAbsoluteOffset(1);

    ts.SwapAnchor();

    ts.MoveToAbsoluteOffset(edit_point.AbsoluteCharOffset, true);

    ts.OutlineSection();

    //ts.Collapse(); // OutlineSection() klappt schon zu



    // Cursor wieder umsetzen

    if (oldAnchor.AbsoluteCharOffset < edit_point.AbsoluteCharOffset)

    {

        // alte Position war im Kommentar -> direkt hinter neue Region

        ts.MoveToAbsoluteOffset(edit_point.AbsoluteCharOffset); // set active point

        ts.SwapAnchor(); //set anchor to active point

        ts.MoveToAbsoluteOffset(edit_point.AbsoluteCharOffset, true);

    }

    else

    {

        // alte Position

        ts.MoveToAbsoluteOffset(oldAnchor.AbsoluteCharOffset); // set active point

        ts.SwapAnchor(); //set anchor to active point

        ts.MoveToAbsoluteOffset(oldActive.AbsoluteCharOffset, true);

    }



    _dte.SuppressUI = false;

}`

Comment: It seem to be the outline-persisting function of visual studio. I solved it now with the IOutliningManager.RegionsExpanded Event. When the region is expanded, my documentopened flag is set and the expanded text is on fileheader is collapse it again. Not cool but working...

Comment: the Event i set in IWpfTextViewCreationListener.TextViewCreated. And don't forget to activate MEF in VSIXmanifest